# Check if user changed list item permission in event receiver?

Tags: permissions, event-receivers

I need log changed permission action using an event receiver, how do I do that?

Comment: Hi there! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible.

Maybe you can take another approach: build an alternate way for users to change the permissions of an item. When the user applies the permissions (using the UI you've built), you can trigger an event, or start a workflow.

Going further, you could replace the default "Manage permissions" option in the ECB and replace it with a link to your custom permissions management UI. More information:

http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2007/08/10/moss2007-%E2%80%93-item-level-menus-investigation.aspx

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90764/sharepoint-event-when-permissions-of-listitems-have-been-changed)